# Where is he vs where he is

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order, questions

> 1. I want to know where he is.
> 2. I want to know where is he.

> 1. I want to know where the hell are we.
> 2. I want to know where the hell we are.

All these sentences are questions, but phrased as a sentence. In question, I know, in a questioning statement, "Where is he?" is correct, and "Where he is?" is not correct. But I'm not sure in the case of a statement. Is there a rule for this? Both statements are valid?

May be only one statement is valid in writing English, but both are valid in casual spoken English?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When asking any question **indirectly**, you must use sentence order and not question order.
So in the first example option 1 is correct, and in the second, option 2 is correct. This applies to both speaking and writing. (It is possible, however, in writing, perhaps in an interview write-up to do something like this: "He asked the President, "Where the hell are we?")

To make it easier to understand, think about an indirect question. That is, 2 questions combined into one.

> Do you know?

Plus

> Where is the bank?

When we combine the two, we will end up with one question (Do you know?) and the second will become "the details" which we can't phrase in question order.

> **Do you know** where the bank is?

**Question** | Details

Comment: but I see people speak both ways.

Comment: It's certainly better to follow my rule. In Britain at least, it would be wrong to use question order twice.

Comment: @T2E I think those people simply air-quote the question, which should be reflected in their intonations. In writing, you can actually quote the question, like this example, *I want to know, "where is he?"*

Answer (score 1):

I have just copy pasted the definition from the book *"Oxford Guide to English Grammar"* for your reference. I hope it will help you.

**Indirect  questions**

We  can  ask  a  question  indirectly  by  putting  it  into  a  sub  clause  beginning  with  a question  word  or  with  *if/whether*.  This  makes  the  question  sound  less  abrupt, more  tentative.

> *We need  to know  **what  the  rules  are.***
>
> *Can  I ask  you  **how  much  you're getting  paid for  the job?***
>
> *Could you  tell  me  **where  Queen  Street is,**  please?*
>
> *I'm  trying  to  find out  **who  owns this  building.***
>
> *Do you know **when the  train  gets  in?***
>
> *I was wondering  **if/whether you  could give  me a  lift.***

There  is  no  inversion  of  the  subject  and  auxiliary  in  the  sub  clause.

NOT *We need to know *what are the  rules.* (Incorrect)

For  question  word  +  to-infinitive,
*Could you  tell  me  **how  to  get  there?***

NOTE  If  the  main  clause  is  a  statement  *(We  need  to  know)*,  then  there  is  no  question  mark.

Answer (score 0):

"I want to know where he is." is a complex sentence with noun clause

- I = subject;
- want = transitive verb;
- to know = object;
- where he is = object complement / noun clause;

= independent clause / complex sentence

Note: "I want to know where is he." is a wrong construction.